# Pthread and C language

Tags: c, pthreads

Here is my code:

```
static long x = 0;
void * thread_func(void *arg){
while(1){
    printf("Thread 2 says %ld\n",++x);
    sleep(1);
}
}
int main(){
pthread_t tid;
pthread_create(&tid,NULL,thread_func,NULL);
while(x < 10)   {
    printf("Thread 1 says %ld\n",++x);
    sleep(2);
}
return 0;
}
```

Now what shall be the output, the book says it will be:

```
OUTPUT
Thread 1 says 1
Thread 2 says 2
Thread 2 says 3
Thread 1 says 4
Thread 2 says 5
Thread 2 says 6
Thread 1 says 7
Thread 2 says 8
Thread 2 says 9
Thread 1 says 10
Thread 2 says 11
Thread 2 says 12
```

Now shall not the first one should be Thread 2 says 1, since the `pthread_create()` is before the while loop in main.
Also how does sleep work here?
Like what exactly is a thread sleeping for, and what process executes when the executing thread sleeps.?

i.e  sleep(1) and sleep(2)  what does 1 and 2 signify?

Comment: `Sleep(1)` DOES NOT MEAN: Hey Thread Number 1, please sleep. It tells the operating system the current thread is le tired and is going to take a nap for ONE (1) second.

Comment: for an exact description of the `sleep` command you may refer to [man 3 sleep](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep). It is generally a good practice to look up the details for every library function you use. The [section 3 manpages](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/dir_section_3.html) are a good reference for the `pthread_...` functions and types as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what book you are reading, but you should stop reading it immediately. First of all, you cannot guarantee that thread will be up and running  before entering a loop in `main`. It could start before or after. Second of all, there is no access synchronization when accessing variable `x` from two different threads, thus no guarantee as for what value it will have. Calling `printf`  synchronizes on `stdout` object, and calling `sleep` swaps the thread out, and it takes a lot of time to schedule it again. This example is useless and assumptions about the output are wrong.

Now, some answers..

> Now shall not the first one should be Thread 2 says 1, since the
>   pthread_create() is before the while loop in main.

Not necessarily. It takes hell of a lot CPU cycles to start another thread. So it is most likely that you will enter `while` loop in `main` before that other thread starts. But, not necessarily.

> Also how does sleep work here?

It tells the kernel not to execute the calling thread for a given number of seconds. The actual sleeping time could be a bit longer due to overhead associated with scheduling. Other threads are not affected by that (well, they are, but not directly, i.e. other threads can have more CPU time etc.).

> what process executes when the executing thread sleeps?

Process never executes anything. It is the kernel's schedule that executes processes (and threads). By default, process consists of one main thread, and kernel executes it. When you create more threads, scheduler executes more threads inside the process etc. When one or more threads are sleeping, schedulers executes those not sleeping. Think of the threads as of processes sharing the same address space - that's what they are.

Comment: what process executes when the executing thread sleeps?

What he probably meant is what thread is running if all threads are sleeping. If no thread needs processor time the processor should be idle. In such a case I assume there is a system thread that calls 'halt' on the processors, which then sits and does nothing until a timer times-out or another external interrupt occurred (like data ready from the harddisc, or new USB device attached). Important for the normal developer is that the processor is not wasting energy on doing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The program has a huge flaw that no multithreaded program can afford to have . I actually allows a global varaible "x" to be manipulated by 2 threads without any sort of synchronization between them . this will surely result in the data contained in the variable becoming inconsistent . Unpredictable output will result . you need to refer to a better book with a good example . basically the idea is to use locks while accessing the variable 'x' .

As others above have pointed out sleep will stop the kernel from executing the thread for the desired number of seconds . I feel that it is being used here as a means of synchronization . however sleep is never a good option as it will not guarantee that the operation on variable 'x' will not become inconsistent . Dont rely on sleep . use locks . An excellent place to start thread programming is

http://cs.tju.edu.cn/orgs/hpclab/course/undergraduate/Ref/POSIXMultithreadProgrammingPrimer.pdf

Its the pthread primer .